# Adding time to a to do list app

Tags: swift, time

I am making a "To Do List" app where you can enter what to do and click submit and it shows up in a table view.

I want to add a time as well, but I cant figure out how to connect a datepicker with the "submit" button then have the time show up in the table view.

can anyone help? thank you.

```
@IBOutlet weak var date: UIDatePicker!


@IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!


@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

        func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true

    }
```

here is the code for the add item page

Comment: This looks like swift, not jQuery

Comment: Does not look like jQuery to me, if I didn't miss alot of new features

Comment: You're correct, didn't mean to put that tag up. Sorry about that. This is swift.

Comment: Can you elaborate the following line: "connect a datepicker with the "submit" button"?

Comment: Do you mean to set the date at time of saving to TableView or you want user to pick DateTime.